# [JavaFx ]What is wrong with this binding?

Tags: java, javafx, binding

So I have created `Instrument` class and `Controller` class. I have big problem with `bindingBidirectional()` method. It gives me an error when i'm trying to bind `Combobox` property with `AmountProperty` in `Instrument` class.

```
amount.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(instrument.amountProperty());
```

What am I doing wrong here?

`Controller class`

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{

@FXML
private ComboBox<Integer> amount = new ComboBox<>();
ObservableList<Integer> amountOptions = FXCollections.observableArrayList(0, 5, 10, 25, 50);

Instrument instrument = new Instrument();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    amount.getItems().addAll(amountOptions);
    //THIS ONE IS NOT WORKING
    amount.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(instrument.amountProperty());

}}
```

And `Instrument` class:

```
public class Instrument {

private IntegerProperty amount = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

public int getAmount() {
    return amount.get();
}

public IntegerProperty amountProperty() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(int amount) {
    this.amount.set(amount);
}
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889638/javafx-properties-in-tableview

Comment: java: no suitable method found for bindBidirectional(javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty)
    method javafx.beans.property.Property.bindBidirectional(javafx.beans.property.Property<java.lang.Integer>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty cannot be converted to javafx.beans.property.Property<java.lang.Integer>)
    method

Comment: in bindBidirectional i need to have this: (javafx.bean‌​s.property.Property<‌​java.lang.Integer>), but it says i have this: (jjavafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty), i have no idea how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IntegerProperty` is an implementation of `Property<Number>`, not of `Property<Integer>`. The `valueProperty` in your combo box is a `Property<Integer>`. Consequently you cannot bind bidirectionally between the two directly, as the types don't match.

You can either change your combo box to be a `ComboBox<Number>`, or use `IntegerProperty.asObject()`, which creates an `ObjectProperty<Integer>` that is bidirectionally bound to the `IntegerProperty`:

```
amount.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(
    instrument.amountProperty().asObject());
```

Comment: @Rocky3582 Please mark the answer as correct if it answers your question